# Create a bar plot in plt when having the bins and heights

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I have the following ranges of bins and their desired heights

```
Range        | Height
-------------------------
0.0-0.0905   |  0.02601
0.0905-0.1811|  0.13678
0.1811-0.2716|  0.22647
0.2716-0.3621|  0.31481
0.3621-0.4527|  0.40681
0.4527-0.5432|  0.50200
0.5432-0.6337|  0.58746
0.6337-0.7243|  0.68153
0.7243-0.8148|  0.76208
0.8148-0.9053|  0.86030
0.9053-0.9958|  0.95027
0.9958-1     |  0.99584
```

The desired outcome is a histogram/bar plot with the edges according to `Range` and the heights according to `Height`.

Comment: Have you tried searching online for `matplotlib barplot`? What did you find?

Answer (score 0):

You can split your Range and explode to get the edges of the bins:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Range        | Height
-------------------------
0.0-0.0905   |  0.02601
0.0905-0.1811|  0.13678
0.1811-0.2716|  0.22647
0.2716-0.3621|  0.31481
0.3621-0.4527|  0.40681
0.4527-0.5432|  0.50200
0.5432-0.6337|  0.58746
0.6337-0.7243|  0.68153
0.7243-0.8148|  0.76208
0.8148-0.9053|  0.86030
0.9053-0.9958|  0.95027
0.9958-1     |  0.99584""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s*\|\s*", engine="python", skiprows=[1])

df['Range'] = df['Range'].str.split('-')
df = df.explode('Range').drop_duplicates('Range').astype(float)
```

This will give you:

```py
     Range   Height
0   0.0000  0.02601
0   0.0905  0.02601
1   0.1811  0.13678
2   0.2716  0.22647
3   0.3621  0.31481
4   0.4527  0.40681
5   0.5432  0.50200
6   0.6337  0.58746
7   0.7243  0.68153
8   0.8148  0.76208
9   0.9053  0.86030
10  0.9958  0.95027
11  1.0000  0.99584
```

Then use `plt.stairs`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.stairs(df['Height'].iloc[1:], edges=df['Range'].values, fill=True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]